# How to prevent VBA macro from stopping when opening other workbooks with runtime errors?

Tags: vba, excel

My macro goes through a range and opens all hyperlinks in it, and looks like this:

```
For Each xhyperlink In WorkRng.Hyperlinks
   xhyperlink.Follow
Next
```

Now, some of the hyperlinks are excel files. In some rare cases, one of the Excel files being opened contains some runtime error inside it - and this error jumps when file is opened, and stops my macro from running. How can I prevent such things from happening? I tried using both 
"On error resume next" and "on error goto X" but that won't stop the message from appearing. 
Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of your macro add:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Then at the end add

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False` might also be a good idea -- unless OP *wants* to run the code in the files that they open

Comment: That looks like the answer, but it creates a new problem - my code also colors every hyperlink being opened, using this code: rng1 = xhyperlink.Range.Address, Range(rng1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6.    Now, instead of coloring the cells with hyperlinks, it instead colors cells in the newly opened excel files. Any idea how to prevent that?

Comment: Probably need to reselect the original workbook before using that piece of code.  `Workbook.Activate`.  Or you can run that code before activating the hyperlink.